# Adding Combo Box to setup using Orca

Tags: windows-installer, installation, orca

I am trying to display a combo box in a dialog during setup of a component. Currently, we have a Radio Button Group. I figured that replacing it with the combo box should be as simple as adding proper entries in the "ComboBox" table in the MSI and in the "Control" table, replacing the references to the radio button group with combobox in the appropriate dialog box. However this is not working. The setup blows up and gives an error #2885. [Windows Installer Error 2885: Failed to create the control [3] on the dialog [2]. from [here](http://www.appdeploy.com/msierrors/detail.asp?id=564).]

Any ideas on how to do this? I can only use Orca apparently (thats what has been used since anyone can remember).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha!! Figured out what it was.
I was doing everything right, except that when i replaced the radio button with the combo box, there was still one element (Previous Button) which had the Radio Button Group as its next element (Sort of like a tab stop). And on form load, it tried to find the radio buttons and could not find them, thus giving the error.

Sort of like the typical new programmer mistakes when dealing with linked lists: Not updating the references to the node which you are deleting/inserting.